# Formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n (i *(i + 1))^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Is any formula for
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (i *(i + 1))^2$$

Comment: By Maple $$1/5\,{n}^{5}+{n}^{4}+5/3\,{n}^{3}+{n}^{2}+2/15\,n$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is any remarcable name or something for it?

Comment: You can write it as $\sum_{i=1}^n (i^2+i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n i^4+2i^2+1=\sum_{i=1}^n i^4 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 + n$. Those two sums can be computed in a whole bunch of ways, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: I do not think so for remarkable name for this formula. I want to suggest to @Ian to write his nice comment as an answer of this question. I find it interesting.

Comment: Caught a simple algebra error in my comment, fixed it in my answer. I'll leave the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Your sum may be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n i^4 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 + \sum_{i=1}^n i^2$. There is a formula to compute those three sums, called Faulhaber's formula, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

As you can see from the article, you need a bit of mathematical machinery to come up with this result (the binomial theorem, or Bernoulli numbers, or similar). However, without knowing anything about binomial coefficients or Bernoulli numbers or the like, you can cook up the Faulhaber formula for a given power $k$ by computing the interpolating polynomial of $(x,\sum_{i=1}^x i^k)$ for $x=0,1,\dots,k+1$. This does not prove that your result is correct for $x>k+1$, but that can be done by induction once you have the result in hand, if you like. (I wouldn't recommend it for $k=4$, though, the algebra will probably get nasty.) Similarly, since in your case you are just adding up three polynomials of degree at most $5$, you could compute your result by getting the interpolating polynomial of $(x,\sum_{i=1}^x (i(i+1))^2)$ for $x=0,1,\dots,5$.

Comment: Is it possible to ask you to explain your interpolating polynomial method more. I try your method in the case $k=1$ that obtain two points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Now, how with the induction an these two points we get the formula $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Thanks

Comment: @Amin235 Thank you, I had a fencepost error. (The interpolating polynomial has degree $k+1$ so it is specified by $k+2$ points.)

Comment: By your introduced method, the points are $$[[0,0],[1,4],[2,40],[3,184],[4,584],[5,1484]]$$ Now the interpolating polynomial of these points is the mentioned formula. Interesting method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Faulhaber's relations*: denoting $S_k(n)=1^k+2^k+\dots+n^k$ $\,(k\in\mathbf N$), you can prove with the binomial formula that
$$\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{r+1}{k} S_k(n)=(n+1)^{r+1} -1,$$
leading to a recursive computation of the $S_k(n)$.  Now
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\bigl(i(i+1)\bigr)^2=S_4(n)+2S_3(n)+S_2(n). $$
Further you may happen to already know that
$$S_2(n)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}, \quad S_3(n)=\bigl(S_1(n)\bigr)^2=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}.$$

Comment: should your first formula be \begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{r} \binom{r+1}{k} S_{k}(n)=(n+1)^{r+1}-1 
\end{eqnarray*}
?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: Oh! yes. An error while copying pasting. Thanks for pointing it! It's fixed now.

Comment: phew ... that was bugging me !

Comment: One should never forget to reread one's answers… Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to exploit [the hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity). We have

$$\left[i(i+1)\right]^2 = 24\binom{i+2}{4}+4\binom{i+1}{2}\tag{1}$$
hence
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left[i(i+1)\right]^2 = 24\binom{N+3}{5}+4\binom{N+2}{3}=\frac{N(N+1)(N+2)(3N^2+6N+1)}{15}.\tag{2}$$
As an alternative, the closed form for the LHS of $(2)$ can be computed from Lagrange's interpolation, since $(2)$ certainly is a fifth-degree polynomial in the $N$ variable.